# HTML table with vertical-align bottom and an element with float right

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table, vertical-alignment

I know this question has been asked to death, but I couldn't find a case similar to this. I have an HTML table, and the "th" row has text that's aligned along the bottom via vertical-align: bottom. Now, one of the headers also includes a button that I want to float to the right and to the bottom. So of course, I wrap that button in a "span" with "float: right". But the text of the header in that column no longer is touching the bottom of the container.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/accelerate/3sqyw/

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2<span class="right-float"><button>Button</button></span></th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
.right-float {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

table, th {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

table th {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

If I remove the "float: right", the "Col 2" will align to the bottom properly, but of course, the button is no longer right-aligned. So what do I need to do to make sure Col 2 is aligned along the bottom with the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positioning instead of floats.

```
.right-float {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

And set relative positioning on the table headers (`position:relative;` on the `<th>`).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3sqyw/2/)**

Comment: I just realized this works only in Chrome and IE, but not in FireFox or Safari. In Firefox, the button is at the far bottom-right of the browser window.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. Basically, setting the "th" to relative won't work in Firefox, but wrapping the entire contents of that "th" in a div with position:relative will work across all browsers

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the issue myself. Odd FF behavior but the div wrapping is a decent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the `height` of the button, you will notice that the label is also adjusting.

```
.right-float
{
     display: inline-table;
     float: right;
     height: 20px;
}
```